# How do I get the floating-point number immediately before/after a given number in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point

Given a `Float` or `Double`, how can I get the next-larger or -smaller one of it? In other words, how do I perform equivalent functionality to [C++'s `std::nextafter` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter)? For example, given `0 :: Float`, I'd want to get `1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125e-45` (which `show`s as `1.0e-45`) as the next-larger one, and given `1 :: Float`, I'd want to get `0.999999940395355224609375` (which `show`s as 0.99999994) as the next-smaller one. If possible, I'd like to know how to do this myself in Haskell, rather than just doing it with a third-party library (I'm fine with something in `base` though) or by using the FFI to call that C++ function.

Comment: I found this https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2003-October/012931.html

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the [**`succIEEE :: IEEE a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.8.0/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html#v:succIEEE) function that will, for a type that belongs to the `IEEE` typeclass (`Float`, `Double`, `CFloat` and `CDouble` belong to this typeclass) calculate the next representable number. Or as specified in the documentation:

> Return the next largest IEEE value (Infinity and NaN are unchanged).

For example:

```
Prelude Numeric.IEEE> succIEEE 0
5.0e-324
Prelude Numeric.IEEE> succIEEE 1
1.0000000000000002
Prelude Numeric.IEEE> succIEEE 0 :: Float
1.0e-45
Prelude Numeric.IEEE> succIEEE 1 :: Float
1.0000001
Prelude Numeric.IEEE> succIEEE (0 :: Float) == 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125e-45
True
```

Answer (score 3):

This algorithm was stolen from mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2003-October/012931.html

```hs
import GHC.Float

nextafter1 :: Float -> Float
nextafter1 0 = 0
nextafter1 x | GHC.Float.isNaN x = x
nextafter1 x | GHC.Float.isInfinite x = x
nextafter1 x = try (abs x)
  where try d = let d1 = d/2
                in if x + d1 == x then improve d1 d else try d1
        improve a b = let middle = (a+b)/2
                      in if middle == b || middle == a 
                         then x + b
                         else if x + middle > x 
                              then improve a middle 
                              else improve middle b
```